# AngularJS - How to use the value recipe as a global variable?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to set a variable and use it globally. By globally i mean just **outside the ng-controller** scope.

The behavior is very simple. When the "gotologin" div is clicked, the login form must show up. same thing goes for register section.

But it seems the variables I used in ng-show directive are different from the one I've defined using `.value` and the controller. They all must be the same.

```
<div class="choose-box" ng-controller="mainController as mcontrol">
   <div class="gotologin" ng-click="mcontrol.gotologin()">Login</div>
   <div class="gotoregister" ng-click="mcontrol.gotoregister()">Register</div>
</div>

<div class="login-form" ng-show="loginclicked === true">
...
</div>
<div class="register-form" ng-show="registerclicked === true">
...
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.value("loginclicked" , false);
    app.value("registerclicked" , false);


    app.controller('mainController', function(loginclicked,registerclicked){

    this.gotologin = function (){
        loginclicked = true;
    };
    this.gotoregister = function (){
        registerclicked = true;
    };


    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the values in the scope like:

```
$scope.loginclicked = false;
....
$scope.gotologin = function (){
    $scope.loginclicked = true;
};
```

Edit:
Or try to broadcast an event with the value you need and in the other controller listen for that event.

Comment: Tried using `$scope` but it didn't work. The problem is not within the controller I believe. The variable I used inside the html page, in the `ng-show` directive is not same as the one we defined in our js file

Comment: Try to inspect the scopes, there is a chrome extention to do that, and you can spot if there are several scopes where these variables are stored.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject app values into your controller like a dependency.

I would do it as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

app.value('loginInfo', {
    loginclicked: false,
    registerclicked: false
});



app.controller('mainController', mainController);

mainController.$inject = ['$scope', loginInfo];
function mainController($scope,loginInfo){

    $scope.loginInfo = loginInfo;

    this.gotologin = function (){
        $scope.loginInfo.loginclicked = true;
    };
    this.gotoregister = function (){
        $scope.loginInfo.registerclicked = true;
    };
}
```

Html will be `<div ng-show="loginInfo.registerclicked">` and `<div ng-show="loginInfo.loginclicked">`

Comment: Um..this is not working. Could you please show a demo?

Comment: Sorry. Fixed some syntax issues. My main point was that you need to inject it. I have updated my answer. Let me know specific errors you run into.

Comment: I see.. but What should I do on the HTML part? How should I write the expression inside the `ng-show` directive ? I tried using your new syntax but again its not working. I really hope I'm not rude cause It's my second day with A-JS and I'm completely lost lol.

Comment: I've tried both `ng-show="loginInfo.loginclicked === true"` and `ng-show="loginclicked === true"` but no luck

Comment: updated. We needed to add `loginInfo` to `$scope` - because front end only sees what is in `$scope`. I have updated the answer. If you are running into an issue - send me the specific error you are seeing.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/c6TMSp0.png This is the error I get in FireBug console upon page load

Comment: No luck :( Maybe its because of my Angular version ? (1.4.4) How come this is working in your computer but not mine ? JSfiddle doesn't have latest Angular, otherwise we could exchange our code and work in there...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88026/discussion-between-simcha-khabinsky-and-xperator).

Comment: I've left my work place at the moment, can I join you in a few hours ?